# Floor Load Guidelines For Second Floor Bookcases

Tags: floor, load

I am considering moving a large number of books in bookcases to a second floor room, and I am confused by the application of live load to this situation.

Each case has a 2.3 square foot footprint, and I believe a reasonable estimate of their filled mass would be 350 lbs each, for a load of about 150 lb/square foot.  Six such cases would be placed in a line next to, but not attached to, a load bearing wall (the separating wall of a townhouse construction.)

I do not have access to the original plan of my home, however I am aware that in Illinois the minimum live load would be a mere 40 lb/square foot.  The home was built in the mid 1980s.

My related questions are:

1) Am I applying the live load formula correctly?  I can multiply and divide and get the pressure of the footprint trivially, but is that all there is to it?  A full bookcase exceeds load guidelines by nearly a factor of four?  This contradicts my intuition-- how does anyone in the United States put bookshelves in a second floor apartment?

2) What are reasonable guidelines for second or more story book storage?

**UPDATE**

- I neglected to mention, the room is a balcony/loft
- Dimensions:  Roughly 15' x 15' plus attached utility closet; see scale drawing
- Note the wall on the east is the one I sincerely hope to be load-bearing, as it is the separator between my neighbor and I.
- Note the dotted line indicating the edge of the loft, and **Note there are no support columns or walls under the edge of that loft.**  This is what has me somewhat twitchy.
- Total estimated weight would be roughly:  3000 lbs bookcases, 300 lbs washer/dryer set in utility closet, 300 lbs two easy chairs and coffee table, 200 lbs one adult = 3800 lbs.  That is a *very* conservative estimate assuming a planned upgrade to sturdier bookcases, some fairly heavy chairs, and includes the load of the washer/dryer for good measure.
- The unit itself is a two story townhome with additional units to the east and west, circa 1985 construction.

[image: Loft Plan]

Comment: Are you putting the bookcase in the middle of the floor or against a wall? If against a wall, can you sort out if it is a bearing or non bearing wall? And is it a single family home or an apartment, different codes to go by I think....

Comment: How many square feet is the room? What will be total load in the room including bookshelves, furniture, aquariums, people, elephamts etc.?

Comment: @Jack definitely against a wall, working on sorting out the load-bearing wall issue.  It's not obvious by sight.  Dwelling is a single unit in a townhouse, and the wall separates my unit from my neighbor's.

Comment: @harper I will measure and update later tonight, including answers to jack.  Total load, however, will depend on what I learn here.

Comment: If it is up against a bearing wall, how much weight you put in it will not be an issue, so placement in a room is everything....

Comment: If you have (small) children, attach the book cases to the wall! That is a lot of weight to topple over onto a small body...

Comment: @jack see updated question

Comment: @Harper see updated question

Comment: The drawing helps but it does not define where the bearing walls are. The loft if anything is typically supported by a bearing wall. The other wall opposite the loft, could just as easily be a bearing wall too. There is a way to help determine if you cannot find the direction the joists go for sure. It is just a "sign" so to speak I call the "first joist sag" This comment space will hold all of my direction on how to determine this and it will not be an answer either, so it needs to stay in the comment box. There is a chance just a word description may not cut it without a picture to help.

Comment: Here goes... When the joists at least, wood joists, span over a given area, they always sag. This is most evident in the center where the sag is the lowest. This, on a bearing wall will not be evident, since presumably all the joists are the same size, setting on a bearing wall. The middle section of joists running by (parallel) the non bearing wall will sag lower approx. 12 to 16" out from the wall that is presumably non bearing. The bridging in the floor system is supposed to keep this from happening but I have seen this "symptom". A short level, 2', on the floor will show this "symptom".